# $1/f$ pole of order $m \implies$ removable singularity.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

> Suppose $f$ has a pole of order $m$, then $1/f$ has a removable singularity.

Basically my book say

> $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}$ and $1/f = \frac{(z-z_0)^m}{g(z)}$ with $g$ analytic at $z_0$ and $g(z_0) \neq 0$

But if $g(z_0) \neq 0$, what singularity is there in the first place?

Comment: There is no singularity in a removable singularity. For example $h(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ is analytic at $0$. Of course when thinking to it as a quotient of functions, the quotient isn't defined at $0$ so you need to make clear why you set $h(1)=1$.

Comment: Wouldn't that be equivalent to saying all analytic functions have removable singularities then? I mean what's the point of talking about it if we know it can be removed.